# Dynamic Data - Implementing IQueryable for List<int> Contains()

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-data, linq-expressions

I have a series of objects that all have a similar property that is a List of the Ids of the groups to which they belong (many parents per child).

I'm having trouble programatically implementing the Linq Expression necessary to make this filter work correctly.

This is what I have so far:

```
IQueryable result = null;

   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.ddlRouteNames.SelectedValue))
   {
      ConstantExpression ce = Expression.Constant(int.Parse(this.ddlRouteNames.SelectedValue));
      ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType);
      MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(pe, this.Column.Name);
      MethodCallExpression mce = Expression.Call(typeof(List<int>), "Contains", new[] { typeof(int) }, me, ce);

      result = source.Provider.CreateQuery(mce);
   }

return result;
```

I'm getting an exception when trying to create my MethodCallExpression:

> No method 'Contains' exists on type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'.

Any pointers on where to begin?

Comment: I'm confused, you had this almost right in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16347794/41071).

Comment: In this question the method was static.

Comment: Other question results in an exception when I try to create the query:  "Argument expression does not implement System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Boolean]."

Answer (score 0):

The `Type` in the method signature you've used:

```
public static MethodCallExpression Call(Type type, 
                                        string methodName, 
                                        Type[] typeArguments, 
                                        params Expression[] arguments);
```

specifies the type that contains the specific **static** method.

You need the type instance for this method to be available - an example (related to your comment):

```
var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "par");            
var inst = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<int>), "inst");
var body = Expression.Call(inst, typeof(List<int>).GetMethod("Contains"), par);
var exp = Expression.Lambda(body, inst, par);
var deleg = exp.Compile();

var lst = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var exists = deleg.DynamicInvoke(lst, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there something similar I can use that will achieve the desired results?  I'm essentially trying to write an expression that will see if the selected Id appears in this object's List<int> of Ids.

Answer (score 0):

Your method call isn't correct, to call the **non-static method** you need to provide instance that contains the method. Here's example of `Contains` method call:

```
var list = new List<int> {1};
//Target for invoke method
var target = Expression.Constant(list);
var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(target, typeof(List<int>).GetMethod("Contains"), Expression.Constant(1));
```

If in your code `me` it's a member that contains `List` the code will be look like this:

```
Expression.Call(me, typeof(List<int>).GetMethod("Contains"), ce);
```

Comment: Getting closer... The MethodCallExpression portion seems to work correctly, now, but when I try to use the IQueryable source to create the query, I get this exception: "Argument expression does not implement System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Boolean]."

Comment: What type of `source` variable?

Comment: source is an IQueryable that's passed into the GetQueryable method, which is overridden from the inheritance from QueryableFilterUserControl.